# An exception was raised while creating "zfcuser"; no instance returned

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I have installed ZfcUser with composer in my freshly installed Zend Framework skeleton.

It is working fine on localhost, but when I deploy it on my production server
it gives me error like this:

> An exception was raised while creating "zfcuser"; no instance returned

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide code? Or any other information?